# problem with class base component and functional component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple to do app in react every thing is okay when my app.js is a class component but when I changed it to a functional component occured an error = **todos.filter is not a function**

my files : Todo.js(functional) --> TodoList.js(functional) --> app.js(functional)

```
function TodoList(props) {
  const [statusDone, setDone] = useState(false);

  let { todos } = props;
  console.log(todos);

  let filterTodos = todos.filter((item) => item.done === statusDone);

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="col-6 mb-3">
        <div className="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
          <a
            className={`nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold ${
              !statusDone ? "active" : ""
            }`}
            id="nav-home-tab"
            onClick={() => setDone(false)}
          >
            undone{" "}
            <span className="badge badge-secondary">
              {todos.filter((item) => item.done === false).length}
            </span>
          </a>
          <a
            className={`nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold ${
              statusDone ? "active" : ""
            }`}
            id="nav-profile-tab"
            onClick={() => setDone(true)}
          >
            done{" "}
            <span className="badge badge-success">
              {todos.filter((item) => item.done === true).length}
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {filterTodos.length === 0 ? (
        <p>there isn`t any todos</p>
      ) : (
        filterTodos.map((item) => (
          <Todo
            key={item.key}
            item={item}
            delete={props.delete}
            done={props.done}
            edit={props.edit}
          />
        ))
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

> main app class

```
function App() {
  const [todos, settodos] = useState([]);

  let addTo = (text) => {
    settodos((prevState) => {
      return {
        todos: [prevState.todos, { key: Date.now(), done: false, text }],
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main>
        <section className="jumbotron">
          <div className="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <h1 className="jumbotron-heading">Welcome!</h1>
            <p className="lead text-muted">
              To get started, add some items to your list:
            </p>
            <FormAddTodo add={addTo} />
          </div>
        </section>
        <div className="todosList">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center ">
              <TodoList
                todos={todos}
                // delete={this.deleteTodo.bind(this)}
                // done={this.toggleTodo.bind(this)}
                // edit={this.editTodo.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> I've tried

```
let filterTodos =Object.values(todos).filter(item => item.done === statusDone)
```

and error fixed but my code dosen't work true

I hope u understand what I said :)

> this functional component is for adding a todo

```
function FormAddTodo(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  let formHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.add(text);
    setText("");
  };

  let inputHandler = (e) => setText(e.target.value);

  return (
    <form className="form-inline mb-5" onSubmit={formHandler}>
      <div className="row form-group">
        <div className="col-8">
          <input
            type="text"
            className=" form-control mx-sm-3"
            placeholder="i want to do ..."
            value={text}
            onChange={inputHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-4">
          <button type="submit" className="  btn btn-primary">
            add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `console.log(todos)` returns something? I mean, data are present in `todos`?

Comment: Please add the `App.js` code too

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito if I change all of todos in TodoList to Object.values(todos) then when i add something it return an object that contain todo

Comment: Could you explain this `props.add(text);`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito well i have a form i need to send value of input
i have function add in App.js

Comment: Is there any way to send source of code to you?

Comment: Create a stackblitz live app. https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on `addTo` function. You are not adding an element to `todos` array but you are setting `todos` as an object with a key called todos that contains an array. Try to modify `addTo` function in this way:

```
const addTo = (text) => {
    let newElement = { key: Date.now(), done: false, text: text };
    settodos(prevState => [...prevState, newElement]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here:

```
function App() {
  const [todos, settodos] = useState([]);

  let addTo = (text) => {
    settodos((prevState) => {
      return {
        todos: [prevState.todos, { key: Date.now(), done: false, text }],
      };
    });
  };
```

your mutation funtion in `settodos` can try to concat prevState.todos with a new todo.

in fact with a useState setter, you get the value directly:

```js
settodos(currentTodos => ...)
```

then return the value that you want (you return an object instead of an array)

also, if you want to concat two arrays, use a spread operator:

```js
const newArray = [...someArray, newValue];
```

so to sum up, here's a fixed version of that piece of code:

```js
function App() {
  const [todos, settodos] = useState([]);

  let addTo = (text) => {
    settodos((prevTodos) => [
      ...prevTodos,
      { key: Date.now(), done: false, text }
    ]);
  };
```